# C# DTO with calculated property

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, dto

I have some DTOs that need save to the redis, and I want all of them have a property or method to generate key of redis.

```
public class Product
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Type {get; set;}

   // Use Property (Maybe Inherit a base class or interface)
   public string CacheKey
   {
      get
      {
         return Type + "_" + Name;
      }
   }

   // User Method (Maybe Inherit a base class or interface)
   public string GetCacheKey()
   {
      return Type + "_" + Name;
   }
}
```

Or... I should not add them to DTO, but I want all the DTOs that need save to redis were must have a key, and each of Key were generate by the property of itself.

Can someone give me some suggestion?

Comment: Generally, a DTO is a data transfer object, it does not include logic. but you  could always add a baseclass with a GetCacheKey method, and inherit from that. then you don't need to include that code everywhere.

Comment: You should create ViewModel or something different with DTO. Becuz DTO should not contain logic

Comment: I agree with @GlennvanAcker, create a base class with this logic and inherit it, and where needed override it in your classes.  DTOs don't typically contain logic but then again all classes have a ToString and Hash function associated with them...

Comment: @cminus So...override in DTOs? Beacuse the generate logic of key were not same

Comment: @Gary if there is no real common way of building the key then you can either override the base class function in the DTOs or create an interface that all of the DTOs implement.  Look at it from the point of what will make the most sense when you look at the code in a few months and be easiest to support.

Comment: Yes, a base class, abstract class and interface will do, but don't overwrite anything in DTO's. DTO's are only meant for transferring data, not logic. make an abstract domain model, and inherit from that in your real domain model. then map that data to the DTO if you want to transfer the data to a client.

Comment: Why you need to have a key as part of the Dto? If you can generate it based on your naming convention as you have it and persist the Dto as the value on redis?

Comment: @GlennvanAcker: Moving logic from a class to a base class isn’t removing logic from the class, it’s just centralizing it. If you’re really committed to not having any logic in the DTO, hiding the logic in a base class isn’t achieving that.

Comment: @NguyễnVănPhong’s comment highlights that, at some point, this is becoming a semantic argument. The right question here isn’t whether or not this is appropriate for a DTO, but whether or not this is appropriate for your type—regardless of what label we use to describe it. There are obviously good reasons why DTOs don’t usually contain logic, but if you’re always deserializing back to the same type then it may not be useful to think of this as a DTO in the most general, platform agnostic sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observing the [Open-Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) of the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)

You should not change the established purpose of a DTO (As @GlennvanAcker said a DTO does not have logic).

However, we can give it an extension method... Which is what I suggest.

```
    public static class ProductExtensions
    {
        public static string CacheKey(this Product product)
        {
            return product.Type + "_" + product.Name;
        }
    }
```

@HansKesting pointed out that I didn't show how to make this work for classes other than Product...

This would require us to extend the base class or interface. If this method is to be applied to multiple classes; the compiler needs to know that the class has the required properties(Type and Name):

e.g.

```
// I'm not calling this interface IDto because I am not assuming that all DTOs have these properties.
public interface IDtoWithTypeAndName
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class DtoExtensions
{
    public static string CacheKey(this IDtoWithTypeAndName dto)
    {
        return dto.Type + "_" + dto.Name;
    }
}
public class Product : IDtoWithTypeAndName
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: An extension method requires a specific class, baseclass or interface. And the OP wants to have this functionality for a number of unrelated classes.

Answer (score 1):

We have to think pragmatic here. The implementation of a cache key getter function is not real business logic in this case.

My suggestion is, create an interface and implement it in any DTO that needs it with the cache key getter function.

An absolut valid approach int terms of pragmatic.